# rsync doesn't copy files although it should

Tags: rsync

```
rsync -rave "ssh -i ~/Desktop/mypemfile.pem" /users/myusername/dev/myproject/wp-content/uploads/* ubuntu@myinstance(changed name).compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/production/wp-content/uploads --omit-dir-times
```

`/var/www/html/production/wp-content/uploads/2018/02` has 50 extra files that are not present in `/users/myusername/dev/myproject/wp-content/uploads/2018/02`

I would like to make sure all files existing in my EC2 instance below ../wp-content/uploads/*.* (recursively) find . their way into my local machine /users/....... /wp-content/uploads - I know I can scp, but scp doesn't do incremental..... I need an incremental copy.

Why aren't the files copied over to `/Users/....` ?

rsync outputs this:

```
building file list ... done

sent 678984 bytes  received 20 bytes  452669.33 bytes/sec
total size is 3691754591  speedup is 5437.01
```

but does nothing.

Comment: looks to me like you're syncing *from* /users/... *to* /var/www, without the --delete flag, which means it's OK that the destination has more files.  Is that the intention with your command?

Comment: I would like to make sure all files existing in my EC2 instance below ../wp-content/uploads/*.* (recursively) find . their way into my local machine /users/....... /wp-content/uploads   - I know I can scp, but scp doesn't do incremental..... I need an incremental copy really.

Comment: You have the arguments backwards. It's `rsync source destination`

Comment: You mention `/Users/` in your text but your command uses `/users/`. UNIX/LInux-based systems are case sensitive and this difference might be important.

Answer (score 0):

The `rsync` command uses the same structure as `cp` and `mv`: the source leads the destination on the command line:

```
rsync  --flags...  /source/path  /destination/path
```

So in your instance the reason nothing is being copied to `/users/` (note, not `/Users/` as in your question text) is because you are copying *from* `/users` to the remote AWS target.

If you wanted to copy *from* AWS to your local filesystem you should be using a command like this (split over three lines; note that the trailing `\` indicates a continuation to the next line):

```
rsync -avO -e "ssh -i ~/Desktop/mypemfile.pem" \
    ubuntu@myinstance(changed name).compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/production/wp-content/uploads/ \
    /users/myusername/dev/myproject/wp-content/uploads/
```

Some optimisations: don't use `*` on the source list (just ensure the path ends with `/`), and `-r` is implied by `-a`.